# Update a .csv file on server from iPad programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, file-upload, download

I am developing a simple iPad application that should submit some text from a form to a .csv file. I could manage to update the .csv file which is saved locally in the documents folder on my computer. However, I need to keep the file on a server, probably download the file, append data, and upload it again (Export a bulk of data to the file on server). Any idea how I could do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess ftp might be the easiest way, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk)

your other options likely involve writing a server-side service to post data to.