# Updating value on a xml located on the web

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a file on the web, that looks like this. I would like to update the value a 1 tag 
Let's say "tempset" and change 150 for another number. How can i do this? NSURLConnection? NSMutableURLRequest? NSURLRequest?  If possible keep it to iOs 4! Thanks!

```
<Courbe>
<age>45</age>
<tempdesi>150</tempdesi>
<vmininit>35</vmininit>
<tempinit>220</tempinit>
<unittemp>0</unittemp><te_fin_c>220,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700,700</te_fin_c>          <vm_fin_c>50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50</vm_fin_c>
<grfan_a>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</grfan_a>
<ecarnuit>0</ecarnuit>
<tempset>150</tempset>
<tempsetp>700</tempsetp>
<jo_cou_t>1</jo_cou_t>
<ty_stcha>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</ty_stcha>
</Courbe>
```

Comment: You need to access it via FTP - Look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354012/uploading-and-downloading-via-ftp-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: What access do you have to your webserver? FTP? SSH? That question is important. If your web server allowed RESTful access, you could update a resource using the POST method.  NSURLConnection versus NSMutableURLRequest is irrelevant at this point -- find out or decide what method of access to write the file is possible first!

Comment: I believe I can access it with FTP but I cannot tell you for sure...until next monday when I'll ask my coworker. But I've heard them talk about FTP so it should be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- create a "service" for this , a kind of API so you can call this service from your client in different languages include ObjectiveC
  like http://myserver.com/myobject/set?tempset=1 
  (in real world, use post and not get for this)

  of course, to do this you need to write some server part in your favorite language
- provide a way to upload the file and replace it completely, a kind of "upload.php"

Which solution is the best depends on your problem: how this file is generated and maintened

Comment: This file is generated by a controller ( a electronic device )